# how to manipulate date formats with phpexcel

Tags: date, formatting, phpexcel

I am using phpexcel to read specific set of data from a excel sheet into an array.

```
// example $cell_range = 'A2:AH35';
$cell_collection = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray($cell_range, NULL, True, TRUE);
```

In this sheet, two columns (L & N) contain dates formates as dd-mmm-yy (01-Jan-16). In order to upload this into database I need to convert this to format yyyy-mm-dd (2016-01-01).

I cannot simply change the last parameter of `rangeToArray` to `FALSE` (formatting retention), because that will just give me a set of x numbers instead of the date.

So how do if reformat the dates? Can be either on the level of phpexcel reading the data or by manupulating the resulting `$cell_collection` array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it manually.... you know which columns contain dates, so return the "raw" MS Excel timestamp and use `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP()` or `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject()` to convert to a unix timestamp or `DateTime` object, and then you can use standard PHP `date()` function or the `DateTime` object's `format()` method to convert to a human-readable date string in whatever format you want.

Alternatively, reset to MS Excel numberformat mask to whatever date/time format you ant for those columns/cells before calling `toArray()`.